# Typescript module-alias import errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, express

I'm currently learning how to create API with typescript using module-alias. When it comes to import some of them works fine, but some causes errors depite of fact that they are written in the same way.

> Example: (this works fine)

```
import PostModel from './post.model';
import Post from '@/resources/post/post.interface';
```

> Example (this causes error)

```
import PostModel from '@/resources/post/post.model';
import Post from '@/resources/post/post.interface';
```

> Error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@/resources/post/post.model'
Require stack:
- C:\code\js\actual\expess-type\dist\resources\post\post.service.js
- C:\code\js\actual\expess-type\dist\resources\post\post.controller.js
- C:\code\js\actual\expess-type\dist\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\code\js\actual\expess-type\node_modules\module-alias\index.js:49:29)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\js\actual\expess-type\dist\resources\post\post.service.js:15:38)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\code\\js\\actual\\expess-type\\dist\\resources\\post\\post.service.js',
    'C:\\code\\js\\actual\\expess-type\\dist\\resources\\post\\post.controller.js',
    'C:\\code\\js\\actual\\expess-type\\dist\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

> My file structure

[image]

> package.json

```
"_moduleAliases": {
    "@/resources:": "dist/resources",
    "@/utils": "dist/utils",
    "@/middleware": "dist/middleware"
}
```

> tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
        "@/resources/*": ["resources/*"],
        "@/utils/*": ["utils/*"],
        "@/middleware/*": ["middleware/*"]
    }
```